# Adding an external script to Nuxt

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I have a script from a third party, that I need implemented on my Nuxt site in the Header.
What would be the best way to insert a script such as this?

```
<script id="sleeknoteScript" type="text/javascript">
(function (){
    var sleeknoteScriptTag=document.createElement("script");
    sleeknoteScriptTag.type="text/javascript";
    sleeknoteScriptTag.charset="utf-8";
    sleeknoteScriptTag.src=("//sleeknotecustomerscripts.sleeknote.com/00000.js");
    var s=document.getElementById("sleeknoteScript");
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(sleeknoteScriptTag, s);
})(); </script>
<!-- End of Sleeknote signup and lead generation tool - www.sleeknote.com -->
```

Usually I would put scripts in Nuxt.config like this.

```
    script: [
      { src: 'https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@0.2.0/dist/lottie-player.js' },
  ]
```

But this one I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in the same way, just place the script into a javascript file and use the path to that file as a script's `src` property value in the `nuxt.config.js`:

```
script: [
  { src: '/scripts/myScript.js' },
]
```

The `myScript.js` would be placed in `static/scripts/myScript.js` in this case

Comment: thanks. I saw that the script is loaded only if I access the website at / and the find my way to /page where /page is where I need the script. Though if I access /page directly the script is not loaded. Did you experience this?